# Sencha touch - How do I run production build?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I ran `sencha app build production` which created a  directory `build/production` where an app.js file is present.
 The question is how do I make the app load the combined app.js file, not the dev files now?

Comment: Isn't there an index.html in build/production ?

Comment: No, there are `resoures`, `sdk` and another `build` folder and an `app.js` file.

Comment: check the sencha docs for details

Comment: Sencha Touch 2 or 2.1 ? Did the build run without error ?

Comment: 2.0. Threre are syntax errors like `1:393779 missing } in compound statement`, but thre are no files with this amunt of lines.

Comment: @amrit_neo The docs are outdated, they don't help.

Comment: what you mean by combined app.js? do you want to say you want to combine model, controllers, view, store classes?

Comment: I guess that's what `buils production` command does. I want to cancatenate and minify the files used im my app.

Answer (score 1):

Check the building guide :

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/building

I have used these commands in my app

```
cd ~/path/to/my/app

sencha create jsb -a index.html -p app.jsb3

sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d ./
```

remember to add all of the classes in app.js.
At the end you will get a minified file and you will still have app.js. but the minified file will contain all of the other classes.